# Get instance value from a class

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a class:

```
class MapImage {
    var name: String!
    var image: UIImage!

    init(name: String, image: UIImage) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

Then I add image name and programmatically created image to my class MapImage. I call in my function

```
 MapImage(name: image_name, image: image)
```

So now I have `image_name` and `image` as an instance of a class. Next, I want to access `image` from `MapImage` with an `image_name`. How can I do that? Basically class holds pairs of `image_name` and `image`. How do I access `image` with an `image_name`?

Comment: Do you have anything like a collection of these instances?

Comment: Something like that. Basically the code would create 3 custom images and then add image_name and image. I need to access those images later in a code somehow.

Comment: I don't know UIImage, just NSImage, but there NSImage has a name property and it is unique. So once you create it with that name the OS will bring it back when you instanciate a new image. Guess it's the same for UIImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a dictionary and access by key. So, put your MapImage instances into a dictionary where the key is the `image_name` from each MapImage instance and the value is the MapImage instance itself. Now you can use a name string to take you directly to the desired MapImage instance.

Alternatively, just put your MapImage instances into an array and loop through the array looking for the one whose `image_name` is the name you're after. This is slower if you have a huge number of instances but with only 3 images it won't be. You can use the `filter` instance method to perform the loop for you and pull out the desired MapImage instance (warning, this code will crash if you supply a bad name):

```
let arr : [MapImage] = // ...
let image = arr.filter{$0.name == "MyDesiredName"}[0].image
```

Comment: Haha Thank You. I think I am working too much need to take a break. That was simple and I was trying to come up with something special I don't even know what... Simple Dictionary<String, UIImage> worked

Comment: Even simpler than what I suggested! :) So basically you just threw your MapImage class out the window?! Always a perfectly reasonable choice...